# My loop and File I/O

Tags: python

How do I get my loop to write to the file until I stop the loop?

For example

```
outFile = "ExampleFile.txt", "w"
example = raw_input(" enter number. Negative to stop ")
while example >= 0:
    example = raw_input("enter number. Negative to stop")
    outFile.write("The number is", example,+ "\n")
```

I feel like im hitting it close but I'm not sure. I wasn't sure how to search for this question in paticular. Sorry, I keep getting a error stating that the function takes 1 argument, when I enter more than 2.

```
import os.path
outFile = open("purchases.txt","w")
quantity = float(raw_input("What is the quantity of the item :"))
cost = float(raw_input("How much is each item :"))


while quantity and cost >= 0:
    quantity = float(raw_input("What is the quantity of the item :"))
    cost = float(raw_input("How much is each item :"))
    total = quantity * cost
    outFile.write("The quantity is %s\n"%(quantity))
    outFile.write("the cost of the previous quality is $s\n" %(cost))
    outFile.close()
    outFile = open("purchases.txt","a")
    outFile.write("The total is ",total)
    outFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you write:

```
outFile = "ExampleFile.txt", "w"
```

you create a `tuple`, not a `file` object.

You probably meant to write:

```
outFile = open('ExampleFile.txt','w')
```

Of course, you could do this a little better using a context manager:

```
with open('ExampleFile.txt','w') as outFile:
    #...
```

---

Your code has a second error:

```
outFile.write("The number is", example,+ "\n")
```

baring the SyntaxError (`,+`), `file.write` takes only 1 argument.  You probably wanted something like:

```
outFile.write("The number is {0}\n".format(example))
```

or using the old style of string formatting (as requested):

```
outFile.write("The number is %s\n"%(example))
```

Comment: Yeah, meant to. I'm sorry. 
With that aside, it still does it. 
Was a answer, or just letting me know?

Comment: @user1861580 -- It would have been doing something different this time.  See my edit.

Comment: actually what I wrote is what I mean to write. This is my first year in computer science, so when my professor does something for a different reason I copy it until I realize that it doesn't always work. 

Regardless, I see what you did there. It clicked a lot more when you did that. Awesome.

Any more advise?

Comment: You could also do this using `print`:  `print "foo","bar" >> outFile`. or in python3 syntax:  `print("foo","bar",file=outFile)`

Comment: What exactly are you doing there? Is that directing it to outFile? If so, how do i make sure it prints on a separate line? "\n"? correct?

Comment: @user1861580 -- `print` adds a newline by default.  I find the `>>` syntax in python2 to be pretty strange.  It's clear that it was borrowed from a shell, but it just doesn't sit well with python I think (which is why I'm glad they removed it in python3.x).

Comment: One more thing. I saw you do it using modulus. I am familiar with that way and was wondering if you could put that back up, or would that not work?

Comment: @user1861580 -- Added the string interpolation.

Comment: speaking of which, when I run my "actual" program, I get this "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting". I have never ran into this one before.

Comment: @user1861580 -- That'll happen if you have something like `print "This,%s,that,%s,other"%("foo","bar","baz")` because you have 3 elements in the tuple but only 2 format modifiers (`%s`).  If you want to include a literal `%` sign, you need to double it:  `print "%d%%"%(33)`

Comment: Ill post what I'm writing in my above post. You can take a look

Comment: `outFile.write("the cost of the previous quality is $s\n" %(cost))` -- You need `%s`, not `$s`.  `outFile.write("The total is ",total)` -- Same error as above.

Comment: Oh man. I really hope my syntax gets better as I continue this major.

Comment: @user1861580 -- Give it time.  You'll catch on. Pay particular attention to the tracebacks (we all make mistakes), but learning to read and interpret the tracebacks are invaluable.